# which data type to use to expect date value in jest

Tags: javascript, datetime, testing, jestjs

in my test

```
    it("should list all tickets", async () => {
    const getTicket = await request(app)
        .get("/v1/ticket")
        .set("authorization", loginResponse.body.accessJWT);
    console.log(getTicket.body.result);
    console.log(getTicket.body.result[0].conversations);
    expect(getTicket.body.result).toEqual(
        expect.arrayContaining([
            expect.objectContaining({
                // _id: expect.any(String),
                // status: "pending response",
                openAt: expect.any(Date),
                conversations: expect.arrayContaining([
                    expect.objectContaining({
                        // sender: expect.any(String),
                        msgAt: expect.any(String),
                        // message: expect.any(String),
                    }),
                ]),
            }),
        ])
    );
});
```

});

i am checking if the value of openAt and msgAt is a date value. But the date value is saved in the string form similar to

```
"msgAt": "2021-12-22T08:29:15.038Z",
```

How to check if the value of openAt will be a date saved in a string format?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringmatchingstring--regexp?

Comment: but i was confused more on why it fails to view it as not being a Date data type

Comment: What exactly do you mean? It's _not_ a `Date`, it's a string.

Comment: I thought Date was a data type. So im assuming only the primitive data types would be acceptable in `expect.any` like string, number and boolean?

Comment: Well it depends what your mean asserting on. `expect.any(Date)` would work perfectly _if the actual value was a Date_. But in this case, where it's a string, it's obviously not going to. _JSON_ can only represent primitives, plus vanilla objects and arrays.

Comment: msgAt uses a default value from `Date.now()` which should be a number type, but when saved and fetched from mongodb it comes out as a string type in the iso standard. what would be a valid Date for expect.any(),  if its not accepting the standard one set by the database, maybe i can change it to that form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just do the following:

```
expect(new Date(msgAt)).toBeInstanceOf(Date);
```

Converting the returned value to a Date and checking if it's a date. If the value is not convertible to date, test will fail.

Comment: "new Date('hello world') instanceof Date" this check doesn't work quite right as it will always return true

Answer (score 2):

a check can be made as follows. getTime function returns NaN if date is not valid

```
    expect(new Date(result.msgAt).getTime()).not.toBeNaN();
```

Answer (score 1):

The type you're receiving is string. You can use regex to enforce a particular pattern for that string.

But if you expect the string you receive is parsable by `Date`, you can use the `parse` method on the string. If the argument doesn't represent a valid date, [NaN is returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#return_value):

```
expect(Date.parse(msgAt)).not.toBeNaN();
```